# Cassandra errors when trying the new CQL 3

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I downloaded Cassandra 1.1.1 and launched cqlsh under the version 3

I tried to create a new column family:

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
 pid          blob,
 period      int,
 targetid     blob,
 sum         counter,
PRIMARY KEY (pid, period, targetid)
);
```

But I got this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./cqlsh", line 908, in perform_statement
>       self.cursor.execute(statement, decoder=decoder)
>     File "./../lib/cql-internal-only-1.0.10.zip/cql-1.0.10/cql/cursor.py", line 117, in execute
>       response = self.handle_cql_execution_errors(doquery, prepared_q, compress)
>     File "./../lib/cql-internal-only-1.0.10.zip/cql-1.0.10/cql/cursor.py", line 132, in handle_cql_execution_errors
>       return executor(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "./../lib/cql-internal-only-1.0.10.zip/cql-1.0.10/cql/cassandra/Cassandra.py", line 1583, in execute_cql_query
>       self.send_execute_cql_query(query, compression)
>     File "./../lib/cql-internal-only-1.0.10.zip/cql-1.0.10/cql/cassandra/Cassandra.py", line 1593, in send_execute_cql_query
>       self.*oprot.trans.flush()
>     File "./../lib/thrift-python-internal-only-0.7.0.zip/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 293, in flush
>       self.*_trans.write(buf)
>     File "./../lib/thrift-python-internal-only-0.7.0.zip/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 117, in write
>       plus = self.handle.send(buff)
>   error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

And on the server console:

> Error occurred during processing of message.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>       at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:247)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.getBytes(AbstractCompositeType.java:51)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.getWithShortLength(AbstractCompositeType.java:60)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.getString(AbstractCompositeType.java:140)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.validate(CFMetaData.java:929)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager.announceNewColumnFamily(MigrationManager.java:131)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.CreateColumnFamilyStatement.announceMigration(CreateColumnFamilyStatement.java:83)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SchemaAlteringStatement.execute(SchemaAlteringStatement.java:99)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:108)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:121)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.execute_cql_query(CassandraServer.java:1237)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$execute_cql_query.getResult(Cassandra.java:3542)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$execute_cql_query.getResult(Cassandra.java:3530)
>       at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
>       at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
>       at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:186)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest reporting bugs at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA.

Comment: I reported it as you suggested

Comment: For future reference, this is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4363 .